# InfluxDB 1.8: Export Measurement Data to CSV, change and import data

Tags: csv, import, influxdb

Using

```
influx -database 'myDatabase' -execute 'SELECT * from myMeasurement' -format csv > Influxdata.csv
```

I exported all myMeasurements values to a csv file.

I changed some values in the csv file (Tag Name change).
Now I need to import the changed data back to myMesaurement.

Is there any way?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using 1.8 and there is no 'write' command. Very disappointing. :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're going to have to manually convert that csv into the format import likes.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/shell/#import-data-from-a-file-with--import is quite useful, but the example they supply is quite limited. All the fields need to be comma-separated before the value and the timestamp are separated by spaces. E.g.:

```
# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: test
data_set,Build=213,Connection=CMD,Database=tpcds,Environment=tpcds62_cold_ni,Query=01,Run=1,Run_Type=POWER value=6.388357 1684159577000000000
```

Then import that with a command like, adjusted for the precision of your timestamps and the details of your file:

```
influx -import -path=test.csv -precision ns
```